# AS3 - Remove Child Problem

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild

I'm using the following code to display an advertisement in a mobile game that I'm working on. It works fine but I don't know what to put in the clickStart function to remove the advertisement from the stage before the game plays. I've been playing around with removeChild but can't seem to get it to work.

```
stop();
startButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickStart);

function clickStart(event:MouseEvent) {
gotoAndStop("play");
}


var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://soma.smaato.com/oapi/reqAd.jsp");
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.adspace = "0";
variables.pub = "0";

variables.devip = "127.0.0.1";
variables.format = "IMG";
variables.adcount = "1";
variables.response = "XML";
request.data = variables;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(request);


function onComplete(e:Event):void
{
var data:XML = new XML(loader.data as String);
var status:String = data.*::status.toString();
    if(status == "success")
    {
    var ad:XMLList = data.*::ads.*::ad;
    var link:String = ad.*::link.toString();

    var l:Loader = new Loader();
    l.load(new URLRequest(link));
    addChild(l);
l.x = 135;
l.y = 265;
    var clickurl:String = ad.*::action.@target.toString();
    l.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onAdClick);

    function onAdClick(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(clickurl);
    navigateToURL(request);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to move the declaration of the Loader outside of the onComplete function, since the variable runs out of scope.

```
var l:Loader = new Loader();
```

You could try placing it on the same scope as these:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://soma.smaato.com/oapi/reqAd.jsp");
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
```

then you should be able to update your clickStart function to something like this:

```
function clickStart(event:MouseEvent) {
removeChild(l);
gotoAndStop("play");
}
```

Comment: You might also want to remove the listener to MouseEvent.CLICK. In addition it might be a good idea to move the onAdClick function out of the onComplete function.